# Finding a record in one of 2 tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, outer-join, join

In PostgreSQL 8.4.8 database I have 2 tables: **noreset** and **track**.

They have *exactly same column names* and contain records identified by unique **id**.

A record can be present only in one of the tables, for example:

```
# select qdatetime, id, beta_prog, emailid, formfactor 
    from noreset where id='20110922124020305';
      qdatetime      |        id         | beta_prog |     emailid      | formfactor
---------------------+-------------------+-----------+------------------+------------
 2011-09-22 11:39:24 | 20110922124020305 | unknown   | 4bfa32689adf8189 | 21
(1 row)

# select qdatetime, id, beta_prog, emailid, formfactor
    from track where id='20110922124020305';
 qdatetime | id | beta_prog | emailid | formfactor
-----------+----+-----------+---------+------------
(0 rows)
```

I'm trying to come up with a join statement, which would find a record by **id** in one of the both tables. The background is that I have a PHP-script, which was always using 1 table, but now suddenly I'm requested to search in both tables.

Can this be done? Is it a [full outer join](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/tutorial-join.html)? I'm confused how to specify the column names in my SQL query (i.e. I must prepend a table id, but which one?)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `union`:

```
select qdatetime, id, beta_prog, emailid, formfactor, 'noreset' as tableOrigin
    from noreset where id='20110922124020305'
union
select qdatetime, id, beta_prog, emailid, formfactor, 'track' as tableOrigin
    from track where id='20110922124020305'
```

(`union` remove duplicate lines, if you want all use `union all`)

If you are goint to use this very often is better to make a view:

```
CREATE VIEW yourviewname as 
select qdatetime, id, beta_prog, emailid, formfactor, 'noreset' as tableOrigin
    from noreset
union
select qdatetime, id, beta_prog, emailid, formfactor, 'track' as tableOrigin
    from track
```

and then your query would be:

```
SELECT qdatetime, id, beta_prog, emailid, formfactor
  FROM yourviewname
 WHERE id='20110922124020305'
```

Comment: Is there a way to see, which table the record is coming from?

Comment: Just add a new column with a literal: 'tablename' as originTable. (I've edit the anwser with this)